# Git : Unable to access configured jar file in git

Tags: git, checkstyle

I was trying to integrate [checkstyle jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkstyle/files/) to my java git project repository to ensure the coding standards. I configured the checkstyle jar and xml file(didn't configured java.command as it taken as default path) as

```
git config --add checkstyle.jar d:/checkstyle-5.6.jar
git config --add checkstyle.checkfile d:/checkstyle_checks.xml
```

Then added the perl script from [here](http://www.cs.unh.edu/~cs415/public/checkstyle-5.6/contrib/hooks/git-pre-commit-hook.pl) as pre-commit hook.
Then changed the java file and add it. While trying to commit the change, the error message showing as `Unable to access jarfile d:/checkstyle-5.6.jar commit abort`

Is there any problem with configuring the jar and xml file.

Comment: Looks like you are using windows, yes?  If so, does `dir d:\checkstyle-5.6.jar` list an actual file?  Maybe you need a `\` instead of `/` in your paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the path syntax problem. Thanks to @bluefeet for mentioning the issue.